# class and interface initialization in java

Tags: java

Below is the code,

```
class Z{
    static int peekj(){
        return j;
    }
    static int peekk(){
        return k;
    }
    static int i = peekj();
    static int h = peekk();
    static final int j = 1;
    static int k = 1;
}


public class ClassAndInterfaceInitialization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Z.i);
        System.out.println(Z.h);
    }
}
```

After following the forward reference rule for static initialization, I see the output as:

```
1
0
```

After `class Z` is loaded & linked, In the initialization phase, variable  `j` being `final` is very firstly initialized with `1`. variable `k` is also initialized with `1`.

But the output gives `0` for variable `k`.

How do I understand this?

*Note: Compiler actually replaces value of variable `j` wherever it is referenced following forward reference rules, unlike `k`*

Comment: One more question : `System.out.println(Z.peekk());` outputs **1** where as `System.out.println(Z.h);` outputs **0**. How?

Comment: @overexchange Yes All the 'J' occurences are replaced by actual Number 1 . See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"j" is a constant so when the code is compiled, j is replaced by the number 1 in the whole program. So if you were an alien and you could read byte code the code would look like this

```
 static int peekj(){
        return 1;// j is replaced by the Actual Number 1
    }
```

Also ***"static variables are initialized when the class is loaded"*** So when the class loads the following statements are executed in sequential manner

```
     static int i = peekj(); // Executed First, as peekJ() directly returns 1 so i is equal to 1
        static int h = peekk(); // Executed Second, Now peekk() returns "THE VALUE OF k" which is not set yet i.e default value of int is given 0(zero)
//So h is equal to 0

        static final int j = 1; // This statement doesn't exist as all j's are replaced with actual Number 1 when we compiled java to .class 
        static int k = 1; // Executed last, So now the value of 'k' is being set, after the value of 'h' has already been set to zero
```

**Note:** 
Do this to get output 1 and 1 i.e i = 1 and h =1;
as the value of k is being set to 1 first.

```
  static int k = 1;
 static int i = peekj();
    static int h = peekk();
    static final int j = 1;
```

Comment: One supple,What are the defaults values of different primitive data types?

Comment: @overexchange
Click Here

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

And Scroll down to see the table

Answer (score 6):

`static final int` will make `j` a *compile-time* constant. So, its value will be present and passed as part of the *byte-code* itself. So, `j` will be 1 when your class is *being initialized*.But `k` is is just `static int`, so its default value will be printed since your static initializer runs before the value of `k` is initialized.

Comment: One more question : `System.out.println(Z.peekk());` outputs **1** where as `System.out.println(Z.h);` outputs **0**. How?

Comment: Once `System.out.println(Z.peekk())` is called, all of the variables are properly initialized (to 1).

Comment: In main method : `System.out.println(Z.i); System.out.println(Z.peekk()); System.out.println(Z.h);`. **Output**: 1 1 0

Comment: In main method: `System.out.println(Z.peekk()); System.out.println(Z.h);`. **Output**: 1 0. No change in output. Note: Even I change the order of SOP then also the behavior is same.

Comment: @NamanGala - Thats because when `h` was being initialized, k was `0`. But `peekk()` returns the current value of `k` when the method is called. You are calling method after the class is initialized. SO, value is 1. got it?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to access `k` before it is initialized, which is why it is 0. (`h` is initialized to `peekk()` before `k` is defined, so `peekk()` returns 0, as fields are initialized from the top down.) `j` is final, so it is execute first; before the declaration of `i`, thus `i` gets the value of `j` or 1.

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) the appropriate Oracle documentation:

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

Comment: The same is happening for `j` also. But it's giving proper result because of compile-time replacement (as stated in TheLostMind's answer).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did it.

Comment: One more question : `System.out.println(Z.peekk());` outputs **1** where as `System.out.println(Z.h);` outputs **0**. How?

Comment: When you say, "*trying to access k before it is initialized, which is why it is 0*", Are you saying that, there is a separate phase prior to initialization phase, where `k` is set to 0? Is yes, what is that phase?

Comment: Basically. Java will provide default values to everything before everything else, before all other code is run (at compile time, IIRC).